# hyperopt SparkTrials maxNumConcurrentTasks([]) does not exist

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hyperopt

I am using hyperopt. I run following code in python:

```
from hyperopt import hp, fmin, tpe, rand, SparkTrials, STATUS_OK, STATUS_FAIL, space_eval

trials = SparkTrials()
       
best = fmin(fn=self.objective, space=space, algo=tpe.suggest, trials=trials, max_evals=iteration_number)
```

but I got following error:

```
  File "~/classes/Algorithm.py", line 507, in random_hyperopt
    trials = SparkTrials()
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hyperopt/spark.py", line 93, in __init__
    max_num_concurrent_tasks = self._spark_context._jsc.sc().maxNumConcurrentTasks()
  File "/opt/spark-3.1.1/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
  File "/opt/spark-3.1.1/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/spark-3.1.1/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 330, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o25.maxNumConcurrentTasks. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method maxNumConcurrentTasks([]) does not exist
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Anybody knows how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you install hyperopt using the below command, you will include all updates that are merged on github but not yet merged on pypi.

%pip install -I git+https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt.git

Comment: I will try that and report back

Comment: Well i tried it, and I get the same error sadly. I'm now going to try windows subsystem for linux, install anaconda, make an environment and try to launch hyperopt with a SparkTrials() object from there, if that fails I might have to look into setting up a mongodb specifically for this task :/